# A question on Financial Data Manipulation

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I have downloaded Financial data that a part of which is given as:

```
data={{"2014-10-01", 387.427, 391.379, 380.78, 383.615, 383.615,26229400}, {"2014-10-02", 383.988, 385.497, 372.946, 375.072,375.072, 21777700}, {"2014-10-03", 375.181, 377.695, 357.859,  359.512, 359.512, 30901200},{"2014-10-04", 359.892, 364.487,325.886, 328.866, 328.866, 47236500}}
```

(*{{"Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Adj Close", "Volume"}}*)

When I try to get the time series of the above data set the following error occurs:

```
TimeSeries[data]
```

(*The argument {{2014-10-01,387.427,391.379,380.78,383.615,383.615,26229400},{2014-10-02,383.988,385.497,372.946,375.072,375.072,21777700},<<47>>,{2014-11-19,373.896,386.481,373.896,380.555,380.555,18931800},<<2959>>} at position 1 is expected to be a list of time-value pairs or a list of states with equal dimensionality. >>*)

I therefore tried this command

```
Table[{Read[StringToStream[Part[data[[i]], 1]], {Number, Number, Number}],Part[data[[i]], 2]}, {i, 1, 4}]
```

to pick Date and Open price from data and then convert "2014-10-01" to {2014,10,1} so that the TimeSeries command works, but the result is

```
{{{2014, -10, -1}, 387.427002`}, {{2014, -10, -2}, 383.988007`}, {{2014, -10, -3}, 375.181`}, {{2014, -10, -4},359.891998`}}
```

Is there any idea that could help me to remove the negative signs such as -10?

The length of complete list of data is over 3000 and I only brought 4 of them.

Thank you so much

Comment: try `{DateList[#][[;; 3]], #2} & @@@ data`?

Answer (score 2):

This will format your data

```
{ToExpression[StringSplit[#1, "-"]], #2} & @@@ data
```

> {{{2014, 10, 1}, 387.427}, {{2014, 10, 2}, 383.988}, ...}

or

```
dates = ToExpression[StringSplit[First[#], "-"] & /@ data];
TimeSeries[MapThread[List, {dates, data[[All, 2]]}]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Chris, the first code worked properly.